# How to Manage and link certain custom taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy

I'm creating some kind of soccer dedicated website.Assuming we created 4 different taxonomies: `Teams`, `Players`, `Tournaments`, `Managers`.

Team includes two different types:

1. National Team
2. Club

Players are linked to club and national team as well, like Messi(Player) is linked with Barcelona(Club) and Argentina(National Team).

Tournaments are of two types:

1. National level
2. Club level

And Last one Managers is also as same as players. How do we do that ? I really need to know how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up...

- Teams and Tournaments as **taxonomies**
- Players and Managers as **post types**.

If you link the taxonomies to both post types you will be able to link both Players and Managers to the same Team or Tournament.

[CPT UI](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) is a pretty good plugin to help create and manage custom post types.

Comment: So do you need to write news articles which reference those top 4 taxonomies?

Comment: Yes Paul, thats what i need. I should be able to write for post for all of those. Like when i write for Messi(Player), I should also get that post on Barcelona( Team) and Tournament(Liga BBVA) which is linked with Barcelona(Team). Thanks again Paul.

Comment: I think you'd need to set up the taxonomy as hierarchical and have teams and tournaments as parent taxonomies of the player or manager. Other than that you're probably going to have to do some custom coding to link separate taxonomies..?

Comment: Those were really tricky. I now directly created category like this way: 

Europe > England > Premier League > Manchester City > Sergio Aguero. 
 
Is there anyway i can change custom first child, second child, third, fourth permalink slug like this Continent > Country > League > Team > Player  ? Thanks again Paul.